# property introspection within a class in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, oop, introspection

Im bulding a class that has a bunch of properties, and looks something like this:

```
public dynamic class MyClass{

    public var property1:someObject;
    public var property2:someObject2;
    ...
    public var propertyn:someObjectN;

}
```

Each property implements a common interface.

I want to be able to go through all my properties, and evoke some functions specified by the interface, without having to print out each property again. Basically something like this:

```
public function printSomething():String{
        var printStr:String = '';
        for(var property:String in this){
            if(this[property] is IPrintInterface ){
                printStr += (this[property] as IPrintInterface).printFunction();
            }
        }
        return printStr;
    }
```

This compiles fine, but doesn't print anything. When i step through it, it seems to skip over the loop, as if "this" doesn't have any properties... Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need - [Iterate Over An Object In Actionscript 3](http://ubergeek.tv/article.php?pid=148)

Comment: Your link contains the right info.  But it would make an even better answer (that I'd +1) if you added the fundamental explanation directly to it.

Comment: Yea, that I don't know. And I also found the type of reflection offered by their library to be cumbersome. It either has to be a technical reason (overhead concerns) or they shipped it as-is.

Comment: yeah that seems more cumbersom than just listing the properties... I think this doesn't work because the "property:String in this" bit might only works on the "Object" class (does someone know this for sure?)... Ill try some things tomorrow...

Comment: I ultimately used this class. It was a lot easier than i had orignially htough. I had to modify it however, since it didn't work (it looked up "variable" fields from "describeType(obj)", when it seems it should look up "accessor" fields)

Answer (score 0):

It is skipping over the loop because in your code:

```
for(var property:String in this)
{
  if(this[property] is IPrintInterface )
  {
    printStr += (this[property] as IPrintInterface).printFunction();
  }
}
```

you are comparing a string variable (property) to an IPrintInterface, which would return a false value.

You need to cast the property variable to an IPrintInterface and see whether that one resolves to an IPrintInterface instance.

Comment: it never actually enters the loop to do the comparison (bascially, its acting as if there are no properties in "this"). Also, its not comparing the string "property". but looking up the value of this at "property", and checking to see if it's a IPrintInterface with "is", which should be valid...